# Apache2 No permission to write file [Errno 13] Permission denied Flask Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, linux, flask, apache2

**A few Details first**

So I did a little web application with Flask.
In theory it should get the ip whenever someone requests or visits the website.
I have everything done (On Windows my Code runs perfectly), but I installed Flask and moved my Project over to a Linux Server where I have Apache2 installed. Ive configured Apache so it handles the requests for the Flask web app.
Everything fine, like my templates load just fine, but the part with logging the ip doesn't work.
I think getting the IP is no problem, tho storing it in say a json file is.
Every time i try to run I get a 500 error on my website.

```
Apache Error Log : [Errno 13] Permission denied  '/opt/iplogs/iplog.json'
```

**The Python Code**

```
def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
filePathNameWExt = path + fileName + '.json'
with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=2)
    fp.close()

@app.route("/")
def getIP():
    visit = {}
    ip_visit = request.remote_addr
    now = datetime.now()
    request_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    visit["IP"] = str(ip_visit)
    visit["date"] = str(request_time)


    writeToJSONFile("/opt/iplogs/", "iplog", visit) # WHEN i comment this function out there is no 500 error
    return render_template("home.html")
```

**The Main Problem**

So in Windows in a Development Envoirement it works fine, but also in linux when i just let Flask run without apache handling its requests
Only when I run the website through Apache I get the error "Permission denied"
So it has to do something with apache and its permissions to write?

Note the folder where my flask(python code) lives is completly different from where the ips are logged
+ I use Ubuntu and i didn't change anything regarding permissions with files or so, heck im even running through root (I know I shouldn't be doing that but its only for testing a very small project)

Thats all I can give you guys

Thanks for all the responses

Comment: How you configured Apache2? Is it simple ProxyPass or something else? Describe how you make your app running.

Comment: I just configured it with mod_wsgi so my python script can be executed. The 000-default.conf (apache) file : https://pastebin.com/GCwGjkHg ; and the flask.wsgi file : https://pastebin.com/xVxvsxqv– bot_diyar 7 mins ago    Delete

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/iplogs/
```

The Apache2 user `www-data` has no perrmission to manipulate this file.

Comment: Yes apache had no permissions to write the file, i guess your solution works too, but for me changing the permissions of the file with `sudo chmod 007` worked. This changes it so everyone can write it, so your solution might be better. But for testing reasons this is enough for me. sorry if i cant upvote your answer i have low rep

Comment: Nice to see you solved the problem. Remember to change permissions back to `641` when going live and obviously change owner as I wrote in answer. Good luck!